# ActiveRecord, NHibernate and PostgreSQL

Tags: .net, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord, npgsql

I'm kinda stuck here and can't get this to work. It seems so simple, but I must be doing something incredibly wrong.

I have a simple class to test NHibernate Active Record and PostgreSQL, take a look

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Accident:ActiveRecordBase<Accident>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Sequence)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public int AddressNumber { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public testAccidentType AccidentType { get; set; }
}

public enum testAccidentType
{
    FRONT,
    BACK,
    SIDE
}
```

And I'm trying to create the schema from my class, like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void StartActiveRecord()
    {
        XmlConfigurationSource source = new XmlConfigurationSource(@"c:\users\h\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestNHibernate\TestNHibernate\Model\config.xml");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, GetActiveRecordTypes());

        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
    }

    public static Type[] GetActiveRecordTypes()
    {
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>()
        {
            typeof(Accident)
        };
        return types.ToArray();
    }
}
```

ActiveRecord is able to initialize this class, but it's always stuck in CreateSchema method. Here is the config file. Any tips from the experts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<activerecord isWeb="false">
  <config>
    <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver" />
    <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Server=localhost;initial catalog=nhiber;User ID=postgres;Password=***;" />
    <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
  </config>
</activerecord>
```

**EDIT: I figured this one out. the problem is that the documentation is wrong. PostgreSQL does not use the keyword "initial catalog" but it uses "database", like this:**

```
    <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Server=localhost;database=nhiber;User ID=postgres;Password=***;" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can post an answer to yourself and accept it. Also, please fix the Castle docs. If you read this in http://docs.castleproject.org/ you can edit it, it's a wiki. If you read it in http://www.castleproject.org/ , you can edit it here: https://github.com/castleproject/Castleproject.org-Site

Comment: I will! I've added a ticket to Castle, but I did not realized it was a wiki.

Comment: The wiki is for users only, and I could not register. I'll try to register to github and alter the docs. How do I merge? Do I only need to merge against GitHub? I just need a github login?

Comment: You don't even need to do any git checkouts or pull requests. Just create a github account, then edit the file. Github does everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the connection string:

```
<add key="connection.connection_string" value="Server=localhost;database=nhiber;User ID=postgres;Password=***;" />
```